# How to correctly define a dispatching function in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, casting

I have the following problem:

1. I receive commands through an `AF_UNIX` socket (no problems about network byte ordering).
2. the first word in packet is the command, the remainder is "parameters".
3. each command has a well-defined set of parameters I coded as a `struct` having the command identifier (`uint32_t`) as the first field.
4. I also have a set of functions handling the commands and accepting the relative `struct` as parameter.
5. I currently have something like:

```cpp
typedef enum {
    Command_a = 0x########,
    Command_b = 0x########,
    ...
} Commands_e;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t command;
    whatever_t param1;
    somethingelse_t param2;
} ParamCommand_a_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t command;
    bool param1;
} ParamCommand_b_t;
...

// forward declarations
void handleCommand_a(ParamCommand_a_t &);
void handleCommand_b(ParamCommand_b_t &);
...

void dispatch(uint32_t *frame) {
    switch ((Commands_e)*frame) {
        case Command_a: handleCommand_a(*(ParamCommand_a_t *)frame); break;
        case Command_a: handleCommand_b(*(ParamCommand_b_t *)frame); break;
        ...
        default: ...
    }
}
```

Since there are a lot of commands (~100) this quickly becomes very tedious and hardly maintainable.

I thought about writing a `std::map<Commands_e, function>`, but I'm unsure this is the right way to handle this specific case.

Also, the explicit casting seems very ugly.

Can someone point me to best practice?

Comment: you still need the 100 lines to fill the `map` though.

Comment: IIRC `enum` is not always 32bit, so `(Commands_e)*frame` is not safe. (with `uint32_t command`)

Comment: You can write a variadic template to read arguments from the socket. E.g. Reader<int, float> would get those two from the stream and have a method to apply them to a function. You can then make each command a class that has the `Commands_e` and a `Reader` (or inherit the Reader). This would make it easy to define each command. Then you can add them all to a `std::map` and call `cmd.dispatch(socket)` once you identified the command. The dispatch handles the argument extraction via the Reader.